# Django change Migration table name in DB

Tags: django, migration

How can I custom the django_migrations table name?

Even I edit the

venv.lib.site-packages.django.db.migrations.recorder > MigrationRecorder > meta = db_table = "ABC_django_migrations"

the makemigrations cannot detect the changes.

I am using Django version: 3.0.5

Comment: Why do you want to customize the name of `django_migrations` table?

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan Due to my client's policy, I can only create several project within one DB. If I don't rename the django_migrations table name for project A, I am afraid that there will be conflict to build another project in the future.

Comment: @WKenny on one server or on exactly one database ( this seems out of mind) ? Also if it is postgreSQL you could use schemas.
There are also some attempts of prefixing all django tables like https://github.com/pydevua/django-table-prefix

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I know it sounds crazy. Anyway, prefix, I don't really get what does it for? can I rename all the default DB table name in this array such as Admin, Auth, Content_type, Session , Token?

Comment: @WKenny it would append prefix on all table names like myprefix_django_session, myprefix_myapp_mymodel etc..

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for your reply first! I tried it just now, it comes up with the error:

AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'rel'

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for your reply! I found the ans: https://pypi.org/project/django-db-prefix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solve this problem:

1. Install the app

   ```
   pip install django-db-prefix
   ```
2. Include the apps in Settings.py

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = ['django_db_prefix',]
   ```
3. Adding the prefix in Settings.py

   ```
   DB_PREFIX = "foo_"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Django migrations don't look for changes in its own migration model

[`MigrationExecutor`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d88365708c554efe3c786c3be6da1d9de916360f/django/db/migrations/executor.py#L10) just ensures that following table exists in database

```
def migrate(self, targets, plan=None, state=None, fake=False, fake_initial=False):

    self.recorder.ensure_schema()

    ....
```

where [`ensure_schema()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3259983f569151232d8e3b0c3d0de3a858c2b265/django/db/migrations/recorder.py#L59) just creates the table

```
def ensure_schema(self):
    """Ensure the table exists and has the correct schema."""
    # If the table's there, that's fine - we've never changed its schema
    # in the codebase.
    if self.has_table():
        return
    # Make the table
    try:
        with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
            editor.create_model(self.Migration)
    except DatabaseError as exc:
        raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
```

you can manually make migration to edit this model ( `AlterModelTable` or custom sql) but I would not advise changing anything regarding migrations